# Difference between Reaction Rate and Rate Law?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

Lets say you have the reaction

$$\ce{$a$A + $b$B -> $c$C + $d$D}$$

The rate of the reaction is given by the change in initial concentration over the change in time.

$$-\frac{\Delta \left[\ce A \right]}{a\Delta t} = -\frac{\Delta \left[\ce B \right]}{b\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta \left[ \ce C \right]}{c\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta \left[\ce D \right]}{d\Delta t}$$

However, there is also the rate expression, which is of the form

$$\text{reaction rate} = k \left[\ce  A \right]^{m}\left[\ce  B \right]^{n}$$

What is the difference between these two, and what purpose does each one serve?

Further, what does the $k$ represent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's use the following gaseous chemical reaction as an example:
$$\ce{H2 + I2 -> 2HI}$$
When we study reaction kinetics, we oftentimes can't observe the changes in concentration of each reactant and product.  Therefore the **rate expression** helps us to relate the rates of appearance/disappearance of the species present:
$$-\frac{1}{1}\frac{\Delta \left[ \ce{H2} \right]}{\Delta t}\; 
= \; -\frac{1}{1}\frac{\Delta \left[ \ce{I2} \right]}{\Delta t}\; 
=\; \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta \left[ \ce{HI} \right]}{\Delta t}\tag{rate expression}\label{rateex}$$
Note that each rate is modified by the inverse of the stoichiometric coefficient.  I explicitly put $\frac{1}{1}$ in the expression just to emphasize this point.  We can see that *multiplying the coefficients of the reaction will not change the rate expression* in the following example: let's multiply the coefficients in the chemical reaction by 2 and then write the corresponding rate expression.
$$\ce{2H2 + 2I2 -> 4HI}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta \left[ \ce{H2} \right]}{\Delta t}\; 
= \; -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta \left[ \ce{I2} \right]}{\Delta t}\; 
=\; \frac{1}{4}\frac{\Delta \left[ \ce{HI} \right]}{\Delta t}\tag{new expression}\label{newex}$$
The $\ref{rateex}$ and $\ref{newex}$ are numerically equivalent.

Full disclosure here: the term *rate expression* is ambiguous and is also used as a synonym for the *rate law*. I've also seen the rate expression referred to as the *rate relationship*.

The **rate law** or *differential rate law* relates the rate of a reaction to the concentration (or pressure) of the reactants.  The rate of a reaction is proportional to the concentration (or pressure) of the reactants modified by some experimentally determined number called the **reaction order**.
$$\begin{align}
-\frac{\Delta\left[ \ce{H2} \right]}{\Delta t}
&\propto\left[\ce{H2}\right]^m\left[\ce{I2}\right]^n\\
-\frac{\Delta\left[ \ce{H2} \right]}{\Delta t}
&= k\left[\ce{H2}\right]^m\left[\ce{I2}\right]^n\tag{rate law}
\end{align}$$
Here, $m$ and $n$ are the reaction orders for $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{I2}$, respectively, and the sum, $m + n$ yields the **overall order** of the reaction.  The proportionality $a\propto b$ can be replaced with an equality $a = k b$.  In kinetics, this constant of proportionality is referred to as the **rate constant**.

---

In summary: the **rate expression** tells us how the appearance/disappearance rates of the products and reactants relate to one another; the **rate law** tells us how the rate is related to the concentrations (or pressures) of reactants and the **rate constant** is a constant of proportionality that comes out of the rate law.

This answer is a summary of information found at the [boundless website](https://www.boundless.com/chemistry/chemical-kinetics/) and from [Tro's](http://www.amazon.com/Principles-Chemistry-Molecular-Approach-MasteringChemistry/) most recent general chemistry textbook.

Comment: How do you calculate the rate constant? Is Arrhenius the only equation for calculating it?

Comment: @Paul Have a [look here](http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Kinetics/Rate_Laws/The_Rate_Law) for information on determining the rate constant.  It is easy to do if you have a first-order reaction, but becomes more complicated for higher order systems.

Comment: @bobthechemisWhich of the following formula describe the rate law (with explaining):
$$ -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta [ \ce{H2} ]}{\Delta t}= k[\ce{H2}]^m[\ce{I2}]^n$$
Or
$$-\frac{\Delta[ \ce{H2} ]}{\Delta t}= k[\ce{H2}]^m[\ce{I2}]^n$$

Answer (score -1):

Reaction rate $\dfrac{dA}{dt}$ is the rate at a specific concentration and a specific time.

Rate law is an equation that shows how (velocity) a rate varies as concentration changes. It describes rates at ALL concentrations and NOT just one specific rate at one specific concentration.

Comment: I am sorry, but I seem to miss how this answers the question, could you add a little more explanation?

Comment: The question is literally asking whats the difference between Reaction Rate and Rate Law